# Angular / Redux correct way to keep the state

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, observable, shopping-cart

I am building up a Shopping cart app with **Angular + Redux**.
I’ve got an array of objects (**Products** in my cart), each of interface:

```
export interface IProduct {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    isAdded: boolean;
}
```

The **Products** in the page have a button *Add to cart*

```
<div class="addBtn" (click)="addToCart(prod)">
    <span class="unaddedItem" *ngIf="!prod.isAdded; else added">Add to cart</span>
    <ng-template>
        <span class="addedItem" #added>In cart</span>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

What I want is to change *Add to cart* text with *In cart* when a product is added. I did it successfully with the **Rxjs**, but when I leave the **Products** page and then go back to it, my *In cart* span for the added products is lost (*Add to cart* is shown again). So, I think **Redux** is the only way to help me keep the state.

I wrote a reducer function with some actions. Here’s one of them:

```
export function rootReducer(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PRODUCT:
            action.product.id = state.products.length + 1;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                products: state.products.concat(Object.assign({}, action.product))
            })
    }
}
```

So, my question **What is the correct way to keep the state of an object after adding it in cart?**
Should I use the same *ADD_PRODUCT* action for that or should I write another action, say, *MARK_ADDED* and use it for another array of added objects? Thus, having two different arrays for *In cart* products and *Marked added* products, where I will keep the added objects and their state accordingly?

Comment: I would create a separate state for the cart and then add product IDs into that. Then the button will get its state by looping through the cart rows and checking if the product id is in there.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your opinion. I'm just confused with the fact that Add / Remove product action is always accompanied by Add to cart / Product added state. So I doubted on creating 2 separate arrays, now I think it may not break the logic of Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't add that logic to your `rootReducer`. [Remember, your reducers mimic the shape of your data](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html). State should flow from your rootReducer to the individual slices of state. In the example below, you'd ideally want a rootReducer that returns your whole state. A products and cart reducer that returns by_id and all_ids and so on until your whole data structure is built.

For your cart and product, i'd be more inclined to have something along these lines:

```
{
  products: {
    by_id: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: "hairdryer",
        price: "2.99",
        in_cart: true
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: "brush",
        price: "299.99",
        in_cart: false
      }
    },
    all_ids: [1, 2]
  },
  cart: {
    products_added: [1],
    saved: false,
    some_data: "foo"
  }
}
```

This follows the structure laid out in the doc examples. When an `add_to_cart` action is dispatched, its object is passed down through each reducer, products will see this data as well as cart. As shown in the docs i'd just use a switch statement in your `in_cart` reducer in products and `products_added` reducer in the cart.

---

Also it's bad practice to add your UUID assignment in your reducer.  A reducer's job is to simply define how the state changes, not define what that state is. Do that in your action or in middleware.

---

I'd also be inclined to pass the whole action through your state as opposed to just one key. That way if you need another part of your action further in your state, you won't have to refactor.

Comment: Can you please explain, how to pass some data to initial state in Redux through http? I used a service for that but it seems like we need no service if we use Redux, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, there are a lot of good tuts on initializing state. Once your state is designed, after you've written your reducers your state should initialize fully without any data in it. You would then dispatch an `init` action on load that get's your data through a RESTful API or some other means. Dispatch a loader etc. You can also look into saving your state using the localStorage API. Dan Abramov created an excellent tut on egghead.io for this

Comment: Depending on your app you don't need to link it to an API though to get your data, you could just persist the state as a JSON file to the server. (make sure you only persist app data and not the UI).